# How to remove error like this (cannot perform __mod__ with this index type: Index)?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, lambda

I am new in Pandas and Numpy. What i try to do here is take **Numpy array** convert  them into **pandas DataFrame**, From this DataFrame i try to take only **odd number of rows** using **.iloc and lambda** ? but it showing error like

**cannot perform **mod** with this index type: Index.**

Can you please help me out here ?

**# Numpy array**

```
df= np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)
```

**# Changing to Dataframe**

```
index = [f'{num}' for num in range(5)]

columnss = list(string.ascii_lowercase[0:5])

df=pd.DataFrame(data=df,columns=columnss,index=index)
```

**# Accessing the rows via index**

```
df.iloc[lambda x : x.index%2 == 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert index to integers:

```
a = df.rename(index=int).iloc[lambda x : x.index%2 == 0]
print (a)
    a   b   c   d   e
0   0   1   2   3   4
2  10  11  12  13  14
4  20  21  22  23  24
```

Or use:

```
arr = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)
#removed converted to strings
index = range(5)
columnss = list(string.ascii_lowercase[0:5])

df = pd.DataFrame(arr,columns=columnss,index=index)
```

---

If need selecting by index with no integers:

```
arr = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)

index = [f'{num}val' for num in range(5)]
columnss = list(string.ascii_lowercase[0:5])
df=pd.DataFrame(data=arr,columns=columnss,index=index)

# Accessing the rows via index
a = df.iloc[lambda x : np.arange(len(x))%2 == 0]
print (a)
       a   b   c   d   e
0val   0   1   2   3   4
2val  10  11  12  13  14
4val  20  21  22  23  24
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution would be,

```
pd.DataFrame(df[::2], columns=list(string.ascii_lowercase[0:5]))
```

O/P:

```
    a   b   c   d   e
0   0   1   2   3   4
1  10  11  12  13  14
2  20  21  22  23  24
```